# Current ROSJAVA message types

Tags: ros, messages, range, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to run the LIstener/Talker example with a Range sensor_msg instead of the string message, but I get the following error:

```
Oct 25, 2011 2:44:09 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger fatal
SEVERE: org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ros.message.sensor_msg.Range
```

I assume this is because range Sensor_msgs are not yet implemented? Is there a webpage that shows which message types are curently implemented?

I've also changed the talker code to be more like the code on the [rosJava msg page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava/Overview/Messages) which uses a messageFactory, but that gives me the same error. Any ideas?

--I've also downloaded an hg clone of the project, but I can't find Range sensors in the source their anywhere.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11673/current-rosjava-message-types/) by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rosjava message code is auto-generated the same way it is for C++, Python and Lisp. You need to depend on sensor_msgs in your package's manifest.xml file and execute rosmake to get the messages built.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2011-10-27**:
Yes, all the files are there in ~/.ros/rosjava/build/sensor_msgs/org/ros/message/sensor_msgs. I also attempted installing ros_java in my ~/ros_workspace folder from the HG version, then adding those jars to my package's build path. Still getting the same result.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-10-26**:
The message class files and jars should be somewhere in ~/.ros/rosjava. Can you check if you can find them there?

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2011-10-26**:
I just d/l the hg version, ran rosmake on it, changed the build path of my  project to point to the new jars from hg version, changed the version number on my project so I can tell the difference between changes, ran rosmake on my project again, rebuilt my jar, and reran the file. Same error.

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2011-10-26**:
I'm using the deb pkg. I downloaded the hg version and attempted rosinstall, but no joy. When I am in the rosjava_core dir, and type "rosinstall ." It says "no source install file". I also have the hg version in Eclipse, but can't figure out how to add it to my current project.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-10-25**:
Which version of rosjava are you using? That one from deb packages or the dev version from the mercurial repo?

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2011-10-25**:
I already had   in my manifest before I ran rosmake, but I ran it again just in case. I still get the same exception.